# Boostrap - automatically repositioned div (vertical vs horizontal view)

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap-3

Please imagine that below shows a phone screen in horizontal (landscape) orientation:

```
+------------------------+
| xxx    xxxxxxxx    xxx |
| xxx                xxx |
| xxx  oooooooooooo  xxx |   
|                        |
|                        |
|                        |
+------------------------+
```

`xxx` mark divs that should stay in place even if the phone is rotated to vertical (portrait) orientation.
`ooo` marks a div that I would like to be dynamic.  That is: if possible it should be displayed between `xxx` divs (as shown above). 
If there is not enough place for `ooo` div (because phone is rotated to vertical display), the div should be shown below `xxx` divs.
Like this:

```
+------------------+
| xxx xxxxxxxx xxx |
| xxx          xxx |
| xxx          xxx |
|   oooooooooooo   |
|                  |
|                  |
|                  |
|                  | 
+------------------+
```

How can such view be achieved? Do I have to create two divs and switch their visibility with media queries?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this may work:
http://bootply.com/zIsGf5c6zP

```
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-3 col-sm-3 text-center">
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-3 col-xs-push-6 col-sm-3 col-sm-push-6 text-center">
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-xs-pull-3 col-sm-6 col-sm-pull-3 text-center">     
    </div>
     <div class="col-sm-6 col-xs-12 col-sm-pull-3 text-center">  
    </div>
  </div>
```